# Find volume of region that lies under sphere x^2+y^2+z^2=4, above the plane z=0 using polar coordinates!

Tags: calculus, volume, spheres

[As you can see, I have done all the working from the image attatched. What I really need help with are the limits I am unsure of, which I have displayed in ? marks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUvFo.png)

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We are dealing with a triple integral in the following form

$$\iiint_VdV=\int_0^2 dz \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} rdr$$

Can you justify this set up?

Comment: No I'm pretty certain that it has to be a double integral

Comment: @FintanColaco by definition, since we are calculation a volume, as initial set  it is a triple integral; then, for calculation, we can of course easily obtain a double integral for example by $$\int_0^2 dz \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} rdr=2\pi \int_0^2 dz \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} rdr$$